# Ingress throwing 404 on gRPC call but able to resolve at regular HTTP GET/POST

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

I have ended with a rather strange issue for a deployment I did on GCP Kubernetes for our golang service that connects over both gRPC endpoint as well as for the HTTP 1.1 calls. The configurations are working fine for http calls, however, as soon as I hit it with my gRPC application, ingress shows a 404 response in the Access Logs, Please review my YAML and tell me if there's anything I am missing that's causing this behaviour

SA Config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: "service-qa"
  namespace: service-qa
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: service-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
```

Service Config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "service-qa"
  namespace: service-qa
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"http2":"HTTP2", "http": "HTTP"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"http2":"HTTP2", "http": "HTTP"}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "service-qa"}'
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: service-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
```

Deployment Configs

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "service-qa"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: service-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  namespace: service-qa
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: service
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: service
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    spec:
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: service
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "REDACTED/service:1.0.0_202310170507"
          env:
            - name: IS_LIVE
              value: "false"
            - name: PROFILE
              value: "qa"
            - name: TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      key: token
                      name: service-access-token
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
      nodeSelector:
        iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"
```

Ingress Configurations

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "service-qa"
  namespace: service-qa
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: service-0.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-internal
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: ilb
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - REDACTED
      secretName: cert-qa
  rules:
    - host: "REDACTED"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-qa
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Backend Configs

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: "service-qa"
  namespace: service-qa
spec:
  timeoutSec: 400
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 30
    port: 8080
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /healthcheck
```

let me also attach some screenshots from my ingress that says the request in incoming but ends up on the 404, whereas when I hit it with a Postman call, I get a proper response
[image: 404 for gRPC calls]

Now the same call through the postman works fine,
[image: postman call 200 ok]

I would also like to point to the part that there's no typo or whatsoever regarding the way I am calling my services as the same code is working fine on VMs - its just that Kubernetes with Google Internal load balancer is not able to take the call forward till the service.

thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated as I have been struggling for quite some time to figure out a solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have:

```
Client
  |
  | HTTP GET/POST Request (Works)
  | gRPC Request (Fails)
  v
Google Cloud Internal Load Balancer (GCE ILB)
  |
  | Ingress (service-qa)
  v
Kubernetes Cluster (GCP GKE)
  |
  | (Namespace: service-qa)
  v
Service (service-qa)
  | Port: 443  TargetPort: 8080
  v
Pods (Deployment: service-qa)
  |
  | Container: service
  | Image: REDACTED/service:1.0.0_202310170507
  | Ports: ContainerPort: 8080 (Protocol: TCP)
  v
gRPC Server / HTTP Server (listening on port 8080)
  |
  | Response (HTTP: 200 OK)
  | (gRPC: 404 Not Found)
  v
Back to Client
```

- For the HTTP GET/POST request, the path from the client to your service and back works fine, and a `200 OK` response is returned to the client.
- For the gRPC request, the request makes it through to your service, but a `404 Not Found` error is returned to the client.

Activate the logs: For gRPC logging, you can set the `GRPC_VERBOSITY` and `GRPC_TRACE` environment variables in your service's deployment configuration:

```yaml
env:
    - name: GRPC_VERBOSITY
    value: DEBUG
    - name: GRPC_TRACE
    value: all
```

If the gRPC client is correctly configured to connect to port 443, the traffic should be forwarded to port 8080 on the server based on your service configuration. However, if there are issues in the Ingress or Service configuration or if the gRPC client is incorrectly trying to communicate using HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2 (which gRPC requires), this could result in the `404 Not Found` errors you are seeing.

Look at the logs for your Ingress controller to see if there are any error messages or other information about why the gRPC calls are failing.

Test your ingress to service connectivity: you can exec into a pod within your cluster and use `curl` or `grpcurl` to test connectivity to your service:

```bash
kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl --restart=Never -- sh
# Then from within the container:
grpcurl -plaintext service-qa.service-qa.svc.cluster.local:8080 list
```

Verifying the client configuration involves ensuring that the client is correctly set up to communicate with your gRPC server, particularly in terms of the address, port, and protocol being used. Here are several steps and commands you could use depending on the environment and language your gRPC client is implemented in:

Check the code where you create the gRPC client and make sure the address and port are correctly set to the address of your service and port `443`.

```golang
// In Go, for example, it would look something like this:
conn, err := grpc.Dial("your-service-address:443", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
}
defer conn.Close()
```

---

The [OP tush4r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2647960/tush4r) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309795/ingress-throwing-404-on-grpc-call-but-able-to-resolve-at-regular-http-get-post/77333338#comment136403751_77333338):

> it seems that the configuration was correct and all I needed was to remove the HTTP annotation and use only HTTP2, further our application was not configured to accept TLS connection and as per the Google docs to use L7 with HTTP2 we need an app that can accept TLS connections.
>
> So that's where I am working now, and rest I think we have caught the issue!

True: the removal of the HTTP annotation and retaining only the HTTP2 annotation aligns with the gRPC's requirement of using HTTP2. That change helps make sure the communication between the Ingress and the service adheres to the HTTP2 protocol, which is fundamental for gRPC traffic.

You can see an example in [kubernetes/ingress-gce issue 18](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/18#issuecomment-816484244).

Enabling TLS is essential for secure communication, and it is a requisite for L7 load balancing with HTTP2 on GCP.

Focusing on configuring the application to accept TLS connections seems to be the right track to follow
Once the application is correctly configured to handle TLS, and with the protocol annotation adjusted to HTTP2, the gRPC communication through the Ingress should operate as expected, resolving the earlier encountered `404 Not Found` error.

Comment: thank you for your response, it seems that the configuration was correct and all I needed was to remove the HTTP annotation and use only HTTP2, further our application was not configured to accept TLS connection and as per the Google docs to use L7 with HTTP2 we need an app that can accept TLS connections. So that's where I am working now, and rest I think we have caught the issue! thank you for your response.

Comment: @tush4r Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.